# Android SQLite-->StackOverflowError

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-spinner, multiple-tables

I'm a beginner in Android. I'm developing an app which has a simple login page without any validation. After clicking log-in button,the next page has to display the tables in the spinner. When I run my app I am getting a StackOverflowError exception.Please help me with a solution.

display.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class display extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    private MyDBHandler helper = new MyDBHandler(null, null, null, 1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
        ArrayList<String> arrTblNames;
        arrTblNames = helper.gettablename();

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arrTblNames);

        arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemIdAtPosition(position) + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is
        present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if(id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

MyDBHandler

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    ArrayList<String> arrTblName = new ArrayList<>();
    private MyDBHandler dbhelper = new MyDBHandler(null, null, null, 1);
    private SQLiteDatabase dbt = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
    public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTSTWO = "productstwo";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";
    public static final String COLUMN_IDTWO = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAMETWO = "productname";

    //We need to pass database information along to superclass
    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
                ");";
        String querytwo = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTSTWO + "(" +
                COLUMN_IDTWO + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_PRODUCTNAMETWO + " TEXT " +
                ");";
        db.execSQL(query);
        db.execSQL(querytwo);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> gettablename() {
        Cursor c = dbt.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);

        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
                arrTblName.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        c.close();

        return arrTblName;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

> error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.StackOverflowError
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:0)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                  at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.java:20)
                at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.<init>(MyDBHandler.jav
```

D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 604K, 27% free 3233K/4423K, paused 12ms+1ms, total 80ms
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

Comment: hey,,,,cause of StackOverFlowError is excessively deep or infinite recursion.
check your code with proper logs.

Comment: which line does a stacktracre point to?

Comment: Because `private MyDBHandler dbhelper = new MyDBHandler(null, null, null, 1);` is called when you create an object with `public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) { super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION); }` which calls the variable init which calls the constructor which calls the variable init which calls the constructor

Comment: I have made some corrections..Now....I'm getting NullPointerException:                      at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.gettablename(MyDBHandler.java:53)==>[        Cursor c = dbt.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);                      
and then
at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.display.onCreate(display.java:29)
below oncreate method in display.java==>[arrTblNames=helper.gettablename();]

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
>     private MyDBHandler dbhelper = new MyDBHandler(null, null, null, 1);
> ```

Remove this field from your `MyDBHandler` class. Each instance of the class creates a new instance of the same class, and this recursion will go on until stack is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Change `display` class like this:

```
public class display extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    private MyDBHandler helper = null; //HERE

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        helper = new MyDBHandler(this, "dbName", null, 1); //HERE

...
```

Comment: I'm getting an error here==>helper = new MyDBHandler(this, "dbName", null, 1); //HERE

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor on MyDBHandler to :

`private final Context myContext;`

`public MyDBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
    }`

Instance of the DataBaseHelper on the display class :

`DataBaseHelper myDbHelpers = new DataBaseHelper(context);`

Comment: I have made these corrections,now I'm getting NullPointerException..                        at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.MyDBHandler.gettablename(MyDBHandler.java:53)
at this line==>[ Cursor c = dbt.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null); ]                      

at com.example.arjun.intentlogin.display.onCreate(display.java:29)
at this line==>[ arrTblNames=helper.gettablename(); ]